# Rails - Add row to nested form table via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.3

Problem: Using jquery to dynamically add new row to table. When adding new row, attribute does not increment.

I'm having some difficulty getting jquery to work with rails. Full disclosure, I've never been too good with javascript / jquery, however I'm trying to understand how it integrates with rails. I'm using ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.0.1.

I have 2 models (Form and Server), however, I'm joining them into one form. This is more of a test as I plan on adding more models and nesting those forms within the new Form partial. Therefore when creating the form, I'm using the accepts_nested_attributes_for option on the form so I can write to the different tables upon submission.

Below are my 2 models:

```
class Form < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :servers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :servers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and

```
class Server < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :form, required: false
end
```

Below is my _form.html.erb partial for Form. As you can see, it also has servers new form nested within. I checked the database and it works upon submission. It creates a new form object as well as the new server object.

```
<%= form_for(form) do |f| %>
  <% if form.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(form.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this form from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% form.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :environment %>
    <%= f.text_field :environment %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location %>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :purpose %>
    <%= f.text_field :purpose %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :accessibility %>
    <%= f.text_field :accessibility %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <!-- section for servers -->
  <table id="server-table" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th class="row-description">Host Name</th>
      <th class="row-description">IP Address</th>
      <th class="row-description">Operating System</th>
      <th class="row-description">CPU Cores</th>
      <th class="row-description">Memory(GB)</th>
      <th class="row-description">Disk Space(GB)</th>
    </tr>

  <div id="server-row">
    <tr>
    <%= f.fields_for(:servers, Server.new) do |server| %>
      <td><%= server.text_field :hostname, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.text_field :ip, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.select :os, options_for_select(["Ubuntu", "CentOS"]) %></div>
      <td><%= server.number_field :cpucores, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.number_field :memory, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.number_field :disk, class: "form-control" %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  </div>
  </table>
  <td><button type="button" id="add-server" class="pull-right">Add Another Server!</button></td>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add-server").click(function(){
          $("#server-table").append('\
          <tr> \
            <%= f.fields_for(:servers, Server.new) do |server| %> \
              <td><%= j server.text_field :hostname, class: "form-control" %></td> \
              <td><%= j server.text_field :ip, class: "form-control" %></td> \
              <td><%= j server.select :os, options_for_select(['Ubuntu', 'CentOS']) %></div> \
              <td><%= j server.number_field :cpucores, class: "form-control" %></td> \
              <td><%= j server.number_field :memory, class: "form-control" %></td> \
              <td><%= j server.number_field :disk, class: "form-control" %></td> \
            <% end %> \
          </tr > \
          ');
      });
  });
</script>
<% end %>
```

When I submit, I notice that only 2 servers ever get saved in the database. The first and the last rows in the table. When I inspect the page, I notice also that the first row has attributes for the first (0) row and last (in this case) (1) row. No  matter how many times I click on my jquery button, the attribute only increments once even though the rows are added.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YaLu.png)
I'm inspecting the 3rd row on my table, which should have name="form[servers_attributes][2][cpucores]

What am I doing wrong here? Why are the attributes not incrementing accordingly?

Edit: I noticed also that of all my `<td>`'s, only the one with `options_for_select` breaks my jquery if I don't escape it with `J` in the erb. Why is that? If this `<td>` did not exist, the others would still work without escaping it with `J`.

Comment: What does the JavaScript look like when it get's to the browser? I'm guessing that it's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up going this route. Instead of using ruby code I added the rows as HTML and incremented each row by one by adding it as a counter  (see javascript below). This is definitely not the "Rails way" so if anyone has  any suggestions, please chime in.

```
<%= form_for(form) do |f| %>
  <% if form.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(form.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this form from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% form.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :environment %>
    <%= f.text_field :environment %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location %>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :purpose %>
    <%= f.text_field :purpose %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :accessibility %>
    <%= f.text_field :accessibility %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <!-- section for servers -->
  <table id="server-table" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th class="row-description">Host Name</th>
      <th class="row-description">IP Address</th>
      <th class="row-description">Operating System</th>
      <th class="row-description">CPU Cores</th>
      <th class="row-description">Memory(GB)</th>
      <th class="row-description">Disk Space(GB)</th>
    </tr>

  <div id="server-row">
    <tr>
    <%= f.fields_for(:servers, Server.new, remote: true) do |server| %>
      <td><%= server.text_field :hostname, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.text_field :ip, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.select :os, options_for_select(["Ubuntu", "CentOS"]) %></div>
      <td><%= server.number_field :cpucores, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.number_field :memory, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <td><%= server.number_field :disk, class: "form-control" %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  </div>
  </table>
  <td><button type="button" id="add-server" class="pull-right">Add Another Server!</button></td>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 1;
        $("#add-server").click(function(){
          $("#server-table").append('\
            <tr> \
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="form[servers_attributes][' + count + '][hostname]" id="form_servers_attributes_' + count + '_hostname"></td> \
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="form[servers_attributes][' + count + '][ip]" id="form_servers_attributes_' + count + '_ip"></td> \
              <td><select name="form[servers_attributes][' + count + '][os]" id="form_servers_attributes_' + count + '_os"><option value="Ubuntu">Ubuntu</option><option value="CentOS">CentOS</option></select></td> \
              <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="form[servers_attributes][' + count + '][cpucores]" id="form_servers_attributes_' + count + '_cpucores"></td> \
              <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="form[servers_attributes][' + count + '][memory]" id="form_servers_attributes_' + count + '_memory"></td> \
              <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="form[servers_attributes][' + count + '][disk]" id="form_servers_attributes_' + count + '_disk"></td> \
            </tr > \
          ');
          count++;
        });
    });
  </script>

<% end %>
```